# RegEx to enforce a typical Forename format

Tags: regex, string, special-characters, uppercase, lowercase

I would like to develop a RegEx that can enforce a typical Forename format that enforces the below:

- First character must be uppercase letter.
- Last character must be lowercase letter.
- Only letters, apostrophe, fullstop, hyphen and space are allowed.
- Consecutive punctuation is not allowed.

For example the following names would be fine:
[John, Jean-Pierre, Smith.Rowe, Harry Smith]

But the following names would not be allowed
[john, Jean--Pierre, Smith.-Rowe, Harry  Smith (two spaces between names)]

Can anyone assist?

Comment: seems simple enough but [why would you want to](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)?

Comment: For validation purposes within a Spring REST API. I can get the first two points working but the others im not too sure how to implement as a regex.

Comment: @jhnc Just on your URL, those are valid points that we shouldnt assume but i have a strict validation criteria on what data can be processed by this API hence the specific limitations. If it bites us later so be it!

Comment: There are many possible "names" that your examples do not cover but that would fit your ruleset. E.g. `A'f'h-D-fG-e.e'q` starts with an uppercase character, ends with a lowercase one and only contains the restricted characters with no consecutive punctuation. Would you really want to match it?

Comment: There is a Verification process external to this where the names are verified against an official ID document. So the issue with non-sensical names being processed should not occur. But a good point to highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below regex may help.
Lower case, upper case matches can be matched with `[A-Z]` and `[a-b]`.
Consecutive punctuations, can be matched with lookaround assertions.

```regex
^[A-Z](?:[a-zA-Z]|(?:(?<![ .'-])[ .'-](?![ .'-])))*[a-z]$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0OXygf/1)

Comment: Thank you this has worked great! I wasn't sure how to define the lookarounds correctly but this helps